# How to call code behind server method from a client side JavaScript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

I am having an JavaScript function for a HTML button click event in ASPX page. And a server Method in its code behind page. Now I want to call the server method from the JavaScript function with some parameters only when the HTML button is clicked by the user.

Please don't change this scenario and also don't use any asp.net contols in the aspx page while replying. Because only HTML controls are allowed. Can anyone help me on this?

Here is the code,

Code in markup:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function btnAccept_onclick() {        
        var name;            
        name = document.getElementById('txtName').value;

        // Call Server side method SetName() by passing this parameter 'name'
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnAccept" value="Accept" onclick="return btnAccept_onclick()" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public void SetName(string name)
{
    // Code for some functionality    
}
```

Answer (score 43):

Yes, you can make a web method like..

```
[WebMethod]
public static String SetName(string name)
{
    return "Your String"
}
```

And then call it in JavaScript like,

```
PageMethods.SetName(parameterValueIfAny, onSuccessMethod,onFailMethod);
```

This is also required :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Are there any security concerns when enabling PageMethods? I'm wondering why it's disabled by default.

Answer (score 28):

In my projects, we usually call server side method like this:

in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("UploadButton").click();
```

Server side control:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UploadButton" Text="" style="display:none;" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
```

C#:

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Hi. This is working fine if there is a click method for my project. I've 2 js function and 2 different onclick method in 2 different asp buttons. One method be called, but the other one uncalled. How is it possible?

Comment: While debugging, I get this error: `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'click' of undefined or null reference`. The button is there on my aspx file and in the code behind it is defined with the event handler attached. Any idea?

Comment: @sab669, by using his method you'll face a small problem where the ClientID is not the same as the server ID. Add the extra attribute `ClientIDMode = "Static"` so the Client ID and Server ID will be the same.

Answer (score 6):

If you dont want to use ajax than

```
Code behind 

void myBtn_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   //SetName(name); your code
}


.aspx file

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function btnAccept_onclick() {        
        var name;            
        name = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
        document.getElementById('callserver').click();
        // Call Server side method SetName() by passing this parameter 'name'
</script>


<div style="dispaly:none;">
  <input type="button" id="callserver" value="Accept" click="myBtn_Click" runat="server" />
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnAccept" value="Accept" onclick="return btnAccept_onclick()" />
```

or use page method

```
.cs file
[ScriptMethod, WebMethod]

   public static string docall()
   {
      return "Hello";
   }

.aspx file

<script type="text/javascript">
      function btnAccept_onclic() {
          PageMethods.docall(onSuccess, onFailure);
      }

  function onSuccess(result) {
          alert(result);
      }


      function onFailure(error) {
          alert(error);
      } 

</script>
```

check this : http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/10/04/asp-net-ajax-pagemethods.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but don't use any controls (asp.net or HTML) having runat="server" tag in the aspx page. And also avoid ajax as possible.

Comment: well second method without any server tags but you need to user pagemethod which use ajax

Answer (score 2):

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function ShowCurrentTime(name) {
         PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(name, OnSuccess);
         }
         function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
          alert(response);
         }
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="IMGBTN001" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/ico/labaniat.png"
class="img-responsive em-img-lazy" OnClientClick="ShowCurrentTime('01')" />
```

Code Behind C#

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
            + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to register my buttonid as a postbacktrigger...

```
RegisterPostbackTrigger(idOfButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the way to go. The easiest (and probably the best) approach is [jQuery ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You'll end up writing something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    // do something when done
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new service and calling it.  The processing can be done there, and returned back.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/WCF-Azure-AJAX-Calculator-4cf3099e

```
function makeCall(operation){
    var n1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
if(n1 && n2){

        // Instantiate a service proxy
        var proxy = new Service();

        // Call correct operation on vf cproxy       
        switch(operation){

            case "gridOne":
                proxy.Calculate(AjaxService.Operation.getWeather, n1, n2,
 onSuccess, onFail, null);

****HTML CODE****
<p>Major City: <input type="text" id="num1" onclick="return num1_onclick()"
/></p>
<p>Country: <input type="text" id="num2" onclick="return num2_onclick()"
/></p> 
<input id="btnDivide" type="button" onclick="return makeCall('gridOne');"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the solution proposed by user1965719 is really elegant. In my project, all objects going in to the containing div is dynamically created, so adding the extra hidden button is a breeze:

aspx code:

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnResponse1" Text="" 
    style="display: none; width:100%; height:100%"
    OnClick="btnResponses_Clicked" />

    <div class="circlebuttontext" id="calendarButtonText">Calendar</div>
</div>
```

C# code behind:

```
protected void btnResponses_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == btnResponse1)
    {
        //Your code behind logic for that button goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// include jquery.js
//javascript function
var a1="aaa";
var b1="bbb";
                         **pagename/methodname**     *parameters*
CallServerFunction("Default.aspx/FunPubGetTasks", "{a:'" + a1+ "',b:'" + b1+ "'}",
            function(result)
            {

            }
);
function CallServerFunction(StrPriUrl,ObjPriData,CallBackFunction)
 {

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: StrPriUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: ObjPriData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) 
        {
            if(CallBackFunction!=null && typeof CallBackFunction !='undefined')
            {
                CallBackFunction(result);
            }

        },
        error: function(result) 
        {
            alert('error occured');
            alert(result.responseText);
            window.location.href="FrmError.aspx?Exception="+result.responseText;
        },
        async: true
    });
 }

//page name is Default.aspx & FunPubGetTasks method
///your code behind function
     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static object FunPubGetTasks(string a, string b)
        {
            //return Ienumerable or array   
        }
```