# Call server method using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, architecture

I wanted to know if you can call server side method using JavaScript or jQuery whilst doing a postback?

I have created a anchor button and want it to work same way as a linkbutton i.e. do postback and call a event. So i thought it could be possible of using JavaScript?

How would i do this? I have done alot of searches on net but could not find anything..

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="SOMEID" onclick="DOPOSTBACK CALL SERVER SIDE METHOD();"></a>;
```

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, not an alternative to JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call code behind server method from a client side javascript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828803/how-to-call-code-behind-server-method-from-a-client-side-javascript-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried searching for ajax?

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

There's lots of tutorials online. If you're using dot net then there's also a JQuery plugin called dot net ajax which I find really useful. However ajax is a huge topic and your question is really broad so it's hard to be more specific!

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is send an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call to the server. But it's a really big topic, you can find a lot of information on the internet.
The simplest form with jQuery is

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="SOMEID" >Call the server</a>;

$('#SOMEID').click(function(){
    $.get('url/on/server', function(data){
        //do something with data returned from server
    });
});
```

This makes an Asynchronous call to the url `url/on/server` and then waits for an answer (since the call is Asynchronous the user can keep on doing things on the page)

Answer (score 0):

Okay you need to postback. Take a look at this article --> http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx

The only catch is you have to call the [GetPostbackReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx) every time a postback happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do postback from anchor tag using javascript, you can do

```
document.forms[0].submit(); //This will post your form
```

OR

```
__doPostBack();
```

OR

If you want to know which control caused postback.

JavaScript

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
       var theform;
       if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("n etscape") > -1) {
           theform = document.forms["Form1"];
       }
       else {
           theform = document.Form1;
       }
       theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget.split("$").join(":");
       theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
       alert(theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value);
       theform.submit();
}
```

With following ASPX code to make it work

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" />
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.