# How to call a method on server side from c#

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, server, backend

I got this QA on stack overflow --[How to call code behind server method from a client side javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828803/how-to-call-code-behind-server-method-from-a-client-side-javascript-function)

**however,** it is call the function from javascript, how can I do it **from c#**. I use **unity3d** to develop an ios app, I did not do it before. Could some one know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

### P.S. about the backend

the backend give these like the below.
url: https://{server address}/register
paramters:

- username, string
- name, string
- pwd, string

and return:
- user_id, int

I run the **server method** with the right parameters, if the parameters are right, it give back a **int/user_id** return.

Comment: what is the actual scenario and your server side code please provide details.

Comment: That linked question is arguably useless due to the huge technical differences between web apps and non web apps.

Comment: @MickyD Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan  And I'll alter the question to post the server codes.

Comment: @tim is this php on server side

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan No, it is not, it is asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a post about this from [this blog -- devindia](http://www.devindia.biz/how-to-post-and-get-json-data-to-a-service-in-unity-2/)

In face, add a `WWWForm` as a secondary parameter to `WWW`, then [it is a `post` to server.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PostJsonDataScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    string Url;
    void Start()
    {
        Url = "Url to the service";
        PostData(100,"Unity");
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void PostData(int Id,string Name)
    {
        WWWForm dataParameters = new WWWForm();
        dataParameters.AddField("Id", Id);
        dataParameters.AddField("Name", Name);
        WWW www = new WWW(Url,dataParameters);
        StartCoroutine("PostdataEnumerator", Url);
    }
    IEnumerator PostdataEnumerator(WWW www)
    {
        yield return www;
        if (www.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Data Submitted");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) unity3d Class, this is what probably you are looking for. WWW is

> a small utility module for retrieving the contents of URLs.

For details to interact with Server (PHP) using C# i'll suggest you this [unitywiki link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores). You will require to do something like this as this tutorial suggested.

```
 IEnumerator GetData()
    {
        gameObject.guiText.text = "Loading Scores";
        WWW hs_get = new WWW(highscoreURL);//highscoreURL this is ur url as u said
        yield return hs_get;

        if (hs_get.error != null)//checking empty or error response etc
        {
            print("There was an error getting the high score: " + hs_get.error);
        }
        else
        {
            gameObject.guiText.text = hs_get.text; // this is a GUIText that will display the scores in game.
        }
    }
```

The reset thing you can customize according to your specification main things to use is WWW with [Co-routine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

Comment: thanks, I got how to get the data through your answer, and how about post data to server, put the data as parameters to the server? Could you help me?

Comment: obviously it is sending data to server using parameter did you check the link

Comment: sorry, I ignored it. Thanks.